# Excel OFFSET function in r

Tags: r, excel, offset

I am trying to simulate the OFFSET function from Excel.  I understand that this can be done for a single value but I would like to return a range.  I'd like to return a group of values with an offset of 1 and a group size of 2.  For example, on row 4, I would like to have a group with values of column a, rows 3 & 2.  Sorry but I am stumped.

Is it possible to add this result to the data frame as another column using cbind or similar?  Alternatively, could I use this in a vectorized function so I could sum or mean the result?

Mockup Example:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:10)
> df
    a
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10

> #PROCESS 

> df
    a   b
1   1   NA
2   2   (1)
3   3   (1,2)
4   4   (2,3)
5   5   (3,4)
6   6   (4,5)
7   7   (5,6)
8   8   (6,7)
9   9   (7,8)
10 10   (8,9)
```

Comment: can you be more precise about what you want the answer to look like?  For a (possibly slightly smaller) example, can you construct the R output that you want by hand?

Comment: Does the `embed` function do what you want?

Comment: @GregSnow: Didn't know that, nice! I have added this as an option to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df$b1 <- c(rep(NA, 1), head(df$a, -1))
df$b2 <- c(rep(NA, 2), head(df$a, -2))
```

Note that the result will have to live in two columns, as columns in data frames only support simple data types. (Unless you want to resort to complex numbers.) `head` with a negative argument cuts the negated value of the argument from the tail, try `head(1:10, -2)`. `rep` is repetition, `c` is concatenation. The `<-` assignment adds a new column if it's not there yet.

What Excel calls OFFSET is sometimes also referred to as *lag*.

**EDIT**: Following Greg Snow's comment, here's a version that's more elegant, but also more difficult to understand:

```
df <- cbind(df, as.data.frame((embed(c(NA, NA, df$a), 3))[,c(3,2)]))
```

Try it component by component to see how it works.

Comment: Fantastic.  I can work with that.  Given the limitation with simple data types in data frames, I don't reckon you could do much better.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JamesKent: Thank you. I have updated my post to include Greg Snow's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:10)
> b=t(sapply(1:10, function(i) c(df$a[(i+2)%%10+1], df$a[(i+4)%%10+1])))
> s = sapply(1:10, function(i) sum(b[i,]))
> df = data.frame(df, b, s)
> df
    a X1 X2  s
1   1  4  6 10
2   2  5  7 12
3   3  6  8 14
4   4  7  9 16
5   5  8 10 18
6   6  9  1 10
7   7 10  2 12
8   8  1  3  4
9   9  2  4  6
10 10  3  5  8
```